# input isnt recognised in if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
choice = input('Are you ready to start the test (Y/N): ')
print (choice)
while choice not in ['Y','N',]:
    choice = input('Invalid choice. Are you ready to start the test (Y/N): ')
    print(choice)
    if choice  == 'N':
        sys.exit
    if choice == 'Y':
        print('Test starts in 3...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('2...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('1...')
        time.sleep(1)
        countdown(t)6
        print('BEGIN')
```

Output:

```
Welcome to type test
You will be given sixty seconds to type as many correct words as possible!
Are you ready to start the test (Y/N): Y
Y
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: @Selcuk Fixed! The indentation was in [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26883e68-bf31-453d-a0ae-d81ef54fa8ea/view-source), but followed by newlines. IDK how that happened.

Comment: @antonin I rolled back your edit since it removed the indentation. Also, you added `import time` without also adding `import sys`.

Comment: no worries, what is the problem to import time without sys? (I use python3). Btw you do not need to indent after the while, maybe that's why he has some issues.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL, since `sys.exit` is used, you need to `import sys`

Comment: `countdown(t)6` is invalid syntax. Please provide a [mre]. Also now that I look at it again, it's not clear if I got the indentation correct. You can [edit] the question.

Comment: oh right, sorry I am coding something in the middle, did not pay much attention. his error is unlikely to be about countdown(t)6 , he would have seen it with the error message when trying to run it... I hope ^^

Comment: When you enter Y or N, it never goes to your while loop. You need to change the condition to '"    while choice in ['Y','N',]:    '''

Answer (score 1):

I used your code locally, with the following indentation, and it run fine:

```py
import time
import sys

choice = input('Are you ready to start the test (Y/N): ')
print (choice)
while choice not in ['Y','N',]:
    choice = input('Invalid choice. Are you ready to start the test (Y/N): ')
print(choice)
if choice  == 'N':
    sys.exit
if choice == 'Y':
    print('Test starts in 3...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('2...')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('1...')
    time.sleep(1)
    #countdown(t)
    print('BEGIN')
```